# How to check that a browser extension content script was loaded on an external iframe contained in the background page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Lets say my extension have a background page that injects an external iframe that in turn runs a content script, something like it's shown in below. What mechanism would you suggest for me to check that the messages the background script receives via `onConnect` and `onMessage` come from the content script that loaded in the background page and not from any other eternal webpage?

**background.js**

```
import browser from 'webextension-polyfill';

var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = 'https://example.com/favicon.ico';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "My Extension",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://example.com/favicon.ico"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "*://example.com/*",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Check port.sender: it won't have `tab`.

Comment: @wOxxOm now that I think of it, that would be a safe bet, since messages not coming from the extension itself would trigger `onConnectExternal` instead.